# Cycle through array back and forth

Tags: javascript

I embarrassed to ask this question its so simple but I can't figure it out, it's been awhile since school.

This is javascript but the question is really a math question. I'm doing an image gallery no library, other than jquery. Basically finds the next image and brings it up.

this is sorta sudo code

```
var array = ["image1", "image2" ,"image 3"];
var currentImage = 0;
var imageMax = 3;

function next(){
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1)%imageMax;
}

//the next I got but the prev i can't figure it out


function pref(){
    currentImage = (currentImage -1)%imageMax; //??? i dont know

}
```

So if i'm at the first image 0 when i hit prev i want to be at index 2

- `next` should go `012012012012…`
- `prev` should cycle `0210210210210…`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can say:

```
currentImage = (imageMax + currentImage - 1) % imageMax;
```

Adding imageMax before you do the modulus operator handles the case where imageMax would be less than zero after you subtract 1.

Comment: Thank you! that did it, i spent like half a day trying to figure it out, i should of came here. I was doing absolute numbers, I did try imageMax - currentImage...so close.. Thank you.

Comment: The valid indices for 0, 1, 2.